# Determine size of a document using Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Is there a method to determine the size of a specific instance of a model/document in a MongoDB using Mongoid?

Comment: I actually figured out a solution to get the number of bytes of a specific document:
    `BSON.serialize(Model.first.as_document).size`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you can get the theoretical size of the document as you illustrated in your comment (`BSON.serialize(Model.first.as_document).size`).

However, it should be noted that this may not be the actual size of the object "on disk". MongoDB will automatically add a buffer to new documents to allow them to grow in-place. When it comes to getting the actual size on disk for one specific document I do not believe this is possible.

However, you can get an average buffer by using `db.collection_name.stats()`.

Answer (score 7):

Solution for 2015 and mongoid (4.0.2):

```
model_instance.as_document.to_bson.size
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for Mongoid 3.1.0:

```
model.as_document.__bson_dump__.size
```

Answer (score -1):

For mongoid 3.x you can use Moped::BSON::Document

for example :

```
your_document = Model.find(id)
# get size
size = Moped::BSON::Document.serialize(your_document.as_document).size
```

Answer (score -1):

Working for MongoID 5.x. With the mongo shell and MongoID is straightforward:

1. Pick up your object id

   `ModelName.first.id # then copy your_id`
2. Run mongo console

   `mongo`
3. Get the size in bytes of the document

   `Object.bsonsize(db.modelname.find({"_id": ObjectId("your_id")}))`

Comment: This isn't what he's talking about. Mongoid is a Ruby ORM for MongoDB.